# (Bug) return wrong values after iterating a list

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator

The purpose of this method is, when i give it a string as input, it has to return me which letter has the most frequent occurrence.

It works correctly if I give a string as input like this:

```
String text = "helllo";
```

so it gives me:

```
The most frequent letter is l with: 2 occurrences
```

and that's correct, but if i give it as input

```
String text = "abbccdd";
```

it gives me

```
The most frequent letters are b,d with: 2 occurrences
```

and this not correct because it has to give me

```
The most frequent letters are b,c,d with: 2 occurences
```

please help!

BusinessLogic.java

```
package com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxBusinessLogic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BusinessLogic {


    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("helllllo");
    }

    public String giveFinalResult(String text) {

        String input = " ";
        String output = " ";
        if (text != null) {

            input = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            int[] freq = new int[input.length()];
            int i, j, max, lastFreq;
            lastFreq = 0;

            //Converts given string into character array
            char inputChars[] = input.toCharArray();

            List<Character> maxChars = new ArrayList<>();

            //Count each word in given string and store in array freq
            for (i = 0; i < inputChars.length; i++) {
                freq[i] = 1;
                for (j = i + 1; j < inputChars.length; j++) {
                    if (inputChars[i] == inputChars[j] && inputChars[i] != ' ' && inputChars[i] != '0') {
                        freq[i]++;
                        inputChars[j] = '0';
                    }
                }
            }

            //Determine maximum occurring characters
            if (freq.length > 0) {
                lastFreq = freq[0];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {

                max = freq[0];
                if (freq[i] == lastFreq) {
                    max = lastFreq;
                }
                if (max == lastFreq && max < freq[i]) {
                    lastFreq = freq[i];
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                    for (Character c : maxChars) {
                        if (c != null) {
                            output = "The most frequent letter is " + c + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurrences";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (lastFreq < freq[i]) {
                    maxChars.clear();
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                    for (Character c : maxChars) {
                        if (c != null) {
                            output = "The most frequent letter is " + c + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurrences";
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (max > 1 && max == freq[i]) {
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                        output = "The most frequent letter are " + maxChars.get(0).toString() + ", "
                                + iterator.next().toString() + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurrences";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Where does that 'iterator' come from? Are you sure you did this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so complex?

You just need 3 simple step:

```
    // collect frequencies
    Map<String, Long> collect = "abbccdde".chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));

    // find max
    long max = collect.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();

    //filter values for max
    String result = collect.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue() == max)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    String output = "The most frequent letter are " + result +  " with: " + max + "occurrences";

    System.out.println("output = " + output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete rewriting:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(giveFinalResult("hello"));
        System.out.println(giveFinalResult("abbccdd"));
        System.out.println(giveFinalResult("hello world!"));
    }

    public static String giveFinalResult(String text) {

        int maxFreq = 0;
        List<Character> listCharMaxFreq = new LinkedList<>(); 
        Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

        // compute occurence of each characters
        for(char c : text.toCharArray()) { // prefer foreach loop
            Integer i = counts.get(c);
            if(i == null) { // character not yet met
                i = 1; // so 1
            } else {
                ++i; // otherwise, increment
            }
            counts.put(c, i); // save new count

            // keep trace of most occurred chars
            if(i >= maxFreq) {
                if(i > maxFreq) {
                    listCharMaxFreq.clear();
                }
                maxFreq = i;
                listCharMaxFreq.add(c);
            }

        }

        // construct output string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("In ")
        .append(text)
        .append(", the most frequent letter is ")
        .append(listCharMaxFreq)
        .append(" with ")
        .append(maxFreq)
        .append(" occurrences.");

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

You should consider to split this method in two parts. First, compute and returns list of characters which are more frequent and their occurence. Second, construct the output String. In this way, you can reuse easily your first method.